# Angular How to split string

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

I am trying to split string using possibly pipe?

I have a string:

```
Alex Santos||alex.santos@email.com
```

I just want the name part

Comment: If you're trying to split the string, show what you have tried. Where is the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "Alex Santos||alex.santos@email.com"
var namePart = str.replace(/\|\|+(.*)$/,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here show you step by step how create pipe  ,  only change the function in return make split how in javascript

var email = "john.doe@email.com";

var name   = email.substring(0, email.lastIndexOf("@"));

console.log( name );   // john.doe

https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/building-a-custom-pipe